# Puzzling around with Get Page ID

Tags: php, get, echo

Please have a quick look at the code below:

```
<?php 
    $pagexfoot = $_GET[page_id]; 
?>

<?php 
    if ($pagexfoot == '5' OR !isset($_GET['page_id'])) { 
        echo 'Hello'; 
    } else { 
        echo 'Bye'; 
    } 
?>
```

So, if the user is on **index.php?page_id=5** then it will echo "Hello" and it will echo "Bye" anywhere else. Now, how do I echo "Hello" on page **index.php?page_id=5** and **index.php** and echo "Bye" on all other pages? Who can solve this puzzle...

Comment: With this code, what appear on page  index.php ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['page_id']) && $_GET['page_id'] != 5)
{
  echo 'Bye';
}
else
{
  echo 'Hello';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if (!isset($_GET['page_id']) || $_GET['page_id'] == 5) {
    echo 'Hello';
} else {
    echo 'Bye';
}
```

We are using the || operator to check if either it isn't set or the value is 5, if so tell "Hello" and else, Bye.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pagexfoot = $_GET[page_id];     
if($pagexfoot != '5' || isset($_GET['page_id'])) { echo 'Bye'; } elseif($pagexfoot == '5') { echo 'Hello'; }
```

You code loks fine to me by try the above code :)